# Unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server after using Microsoft.Web.Administration

Tags: .net, iis-express, servermanager

I have been playing around with Microsoft.Web.Administration and I have had the following code run in my settup:

```
            {
                using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
                {
                    foreach (Site site in serverManager.Sites)
                    {
                        site.Delete();
                    }

                    foreach (var applicationPool in serverManager.ApplicationPools)
                    {
                        applicationPool.Delete();
                    }

                    serverManager.CommitChanges();
                }
            }
```

Today I am not able, when create a new site in visual studio to start IIS Express.

I have uninstalled and installed it again with same results.

> C:\Users\s093294>"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"
>   /trace:error Starting IIS Express ... Process Model Shutdown called
>   Unable to start iisexpress.
>
> The object identifier does not represent a valid object. For more
>   information about the error, run iisexpress.exe with the tracing
>   switch  enabled (/trace:error).
>
> C:\Users\s093294>

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably your applicationhost.config file (located in %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config) was corrupted. Take a backup of this applicationhost.config file and delete it and then re-create the site from visual studio. (IIS Express would recreate the config file)

Comment: had to start Iis from command line after deleting the file then it worked.

Comment: The code removes critical items from the configuration. No doubt IIS Express is broken.